# How about a "View more hot meta posts" button?

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

As we all know,we can see the "Hot Meta Posts" at the right side of the page. Also,we can see the "Hot Network Questions" at the right side of the page below the "Hot Meta Posts".

At times I've noticed that there appears a <kbd>more hot questions</kbd> button that when pressed,shows some more hot network questions. Also,one can click the title("Hot Network Questions") to see more questions.

But for the "Hot meta posts",there isn't a button and the title isn't a link either! Why not create a button named <kbd>more hot questions</kbd> or <kbd>View more hot meta questions</kbd> and place it just below the 3 hot meta posts?

Answer (score 3):

There is the ["Hot" tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot). You can get to it if you click the Stack Overflow Meta logo and then click the Hot tab.

[image]